# How to pass multiply dictionaries as function arguments? One dict as reference and one as a copy

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments

I have a function that needs two dictionaries, one as a copy and one as a reference.
I got this.

```
_start_value = 0.00724
_second_value = 42700.0
_result = 0.0
_delta = 0.0


data1 = {'start_value':_start_value, 'second_value': _second_value }
data2 = {'result' : result, 'delta': delta}

# working with two local dicts
def my_function_1(data_1, data_2):        # works fine
    _value1 = data_1['start_value']
    _value2 = data_1['second_value']

    res = data_2['result'] + _value1 + _value2
    data_2['delta'] = res - data_2['result']
    data_2['result'] = res

    return res

print(my_function_1(tradeData, tradeWorkingData ))
print(data1, data2)


# working with a LOCAL copy and GLOBAL
def my_function_2(data2, **data):        # works fine
    _value1 = data_1['start_value']
    _value2 = data_1['second_value']

    res = data_2['result'] + _value1 + _value2
    data_2['delta'] = res - data_2['result']
    data_2['result'] = res

    return res

print(my_function_2(data2, **data1 ))
print(data1, data2)

# working with a GLOBAL and LOKAL copy
def my_function_3(**data_1, data_2):        # doesn't work
    _value1 = data_1['start_value']
    _value2 = data_1['second_value']

    res = data_2['result'] + _value1 + _value2
    data_2['delta'] = res - data_2['result']
    data_2['result'] = res

    return res

print(my_function_3(**data1, data2 ))
print(data1, data2)
```

I did read the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)
Why is the latter function not working? I ment to ask why did they do it this way?

I would love to change the order so it should be like in the last function ( my_function_3 ) this to have it more logical in this situation. The code is just here to show the issue.

Any suggestions to make this work? What is the technical reason that they make the interpreter refuses this order of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the difference between `**` on dictionary and `**` in function definition.

- `**` on dictionary, like `func(**d)` means "pass the key-value pairs in the dictionary as additional named arguments to function `func`."

```py
def foo(x, y):
    print(x, y)

foo(**{'x':1, 'y':2}) # Output: 1 2
foo(**{'z':1, 'y':2}) # Gives error because `foo` function doesn't have an argument named `z`
```

- `**` in in function definition should be added on the last item, like `func(x, **kwargs)`. It means "take all additional arguments and/or keyword arguments passed to this function and insert them into parameter `kwargs` as dictionary entries."

```py
def foo(**d):
    print(d)

foo(x=1, y=2) # Output: {'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Let's see your `my_function_2()`.

```py
def my_function_2(data_2, **data_1):        # works fine
    _value1 = data_1['start_value']
    _value2 = data_1['second_value']

    res = data_2['result'] + _value1 + _value2

    data_2['delta'] = res - data_2['result']
    data_2['result'] = res
    return res

print(my_function_2(data2, **data1))
print(data1, data2)
```

You are calling `my_function_2()` with argument `data2` and `**data1`.

- With `**data1`, it passes the key-value pairs in the dictionary as additional named arguments to `my_function_2()`.
- With `my_function_2(data_2, **data_1)`, `**data_1` takes all the additional arguments as dictionary.

It's just a coincidence that `data1` out of function and `data_1` in the function are same.

If you do something like `my_function_2(data_2, **data_1, x=3)`, it will be different.

Let's move on to `my_function_3()`

```py
def my_function_3(**data_1, data_2):        # doesn't work
    _value1 = data_1['start_value']
    _value2 = data_1['second_value']

    res = data_2['result'] + _value1 + _value2
    data_2['delta'] = res - data_2['result']
    data_2['result'] = res

    return res
```

There is a rule in function definition, `**kwargs` should be the last item in your function definition’s argument list. However, in `my_function_3(**data_1, data_2)`, you put it ahead.

If you want to use a copy of dictionary, you could use [dict.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy), rather than use `**` on dictionary.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It clarifies a lot. I will check your comment out. dict.copy() is also nice to know about. I didn't think about it. Still just unexperienced ( or is it inexperienced ?). Pity about the rule, I did read that but just want to know why. Again thank you. BTW, I did wrote GLOBAL and LOCAL above in the code. But this isn't the right word, is there a better word for that? English is not my native language.

Comment: I think it's fine, I can understand what you mean. English is not my native language either.